# Serialization, compile time check Vs runtime check

Tags: java, serializable, marker-interfaces

When going through how marker interfaces are used in Java, I found writeObject method from ObjectOutputStream class. It receives instance of Object as input and do serialization only when given argument is an instance of Serializable.

Why not writeObject method receives instance of Serializable as input instead of Object, so that type check is done during compile time? What is the reason behind making argument type as Object and perform instanceOf check against Serializable?

Answer (score 0):

For serialization to work, `Object` needs to be instance of `Serializable`. For writing an object, however, you may see that from jdk sources, there are methods of `Object` class being called within the `writeObject`. A simple e.g. being `obj.getClass()`.

So if the `writeObject` method were to take `Serializable` as input, ultimately for referencing methods like `obj.getClass()`, it would have to be cast to `Object` anyway.